# Binary Tree void function

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, void

Hey Guys I'm supposed to write a function which inserts a given node into my BT root.
 After inserting the node the tree should remain the standards of a BST.
 My function returns an error that says "void value not ignored as it ought to be in the     recursive definition. please give me a hint whats wrong.

```
void InsertNode(Node* root, Node* node){
    if(root == NULL) {
            root = node;
    }

    else if(node->value <= root->value ){
        root->left = InsertNode(root->left,node);
    }

    else{
        root->right = InsertNode(root->right,node);
    }
    return ;
}
```

So how can I assign the given node of this structure:

```
struct Node{
int value; 
Node* left; 
Node* right; 
};
```

to the empty tree root?

```
void InsertNode(Node* root, Node* node){
if (node->value==root->value) return;

if(node->value < root->value){
         root->left =  node;
         node->left++;
        }
if (node->value>root->value){
        root->right = node;
        node->right++;

 }
 }
```

So now I have this Idea of my function is it right to increment both pointers to go through the tree?

Comment: `root->right = InsertNode(...)` Does not match the signature of the method. What is actually the return type?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign a `void` to a variable.  This doesn't make sense to the compiler.

Your function wouldn't work anyway BTW.  Assigning `node` to `root` won't do anything that persists beyond the body of the `InsertNode` function.

Comment: so you say I can't assign the variable root->left a recursive function of type void ? But how can I go through my tree without a recursive definition ?

Comment: Well, the recursion really has nothing to do with it, it's the return value (or lack thereof) you decided on.  As to how else you would do it, well you can convert any recursion into iteration so there's that.  The main part of your problem is that `void` isn't a value--it makes no sense therefor for it to appear in an assignment expression.  So return something other than `void` maybe?